# Integral zeros of quadratic forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, quadratic-forms

Suppose I have a definite quadratic form over $\mathbb{Z}$ in $n$ variables
$$Q(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{i,j} a_{i,j}x_ix_j$$

I'm looking to find whether an integer $m$ is representable by $Q$. Everyone recommends using the Hasse principle. For some of the examples I'm looking at, I've checked the first 5000 primes and I've found no local obstructions to solving $Q(\mathbf{x})=m$. So, I should be able to use the chinese remainder theorem to piece together a solution over $\mathbb{Z}$; however, there are multiple solutions for each prime and I don't know a priori which ones to pick so that my solution over $\mathbb{Z}$ isn't too big (that way I can find it relatively quickly). Is there a way to pick good primes/solutions modulo primes so that I can find a solution over $\mathbb{Z}$ more easily.

I don't care too much about how long it takes to find a solution; I just want to be able to find one.

Comment: The Hasse principle works over the rationals, not the integers. That is, solvability modulo any prime power does not imply solvability over the integers. Finding which integers are representable can be rather tricky, see e.g. Ono-Soundararajan: Ramanujan's ternary quadratic form.

Comment: Please share  some of your examples of interest.  I can't tell what you intend for dimension $n.$

Comment: As far as  $x^2 + y^2 + 10 z^2,$  every eligible number is represented by a form in the genus; this is a result  of B. W. Jones.  The competition for this one is $ 2x^2 + 2 y^2 + 3 z^2 + 2 zx $

Comment: all those numbers are integrally represented by $x^2 + y^2 + 3 z^2 + yz + zx$

Comment: So, you have a (finite) list of primes $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n$, and for each $p_i$ you have a (non-empty) set $A_i$ of residues modulo $p_i$, and you want a "small" integer $x$ such that for all $i$, $x$ reduced modulo $p_i$ is in $A_i$. I think that is, in general, a hard computational problem.

Comment: I know it's going to be a hard problem; I'm wondering if there is an algorithm for finding integral solutions. I don't care how slow it is, I just need a method that is *slightly* better than exhaustive checking. I thought lifting solutions modulo p might help, but since there are many solutions modulo each prime, it's hard to know which ones will lift to a solution over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Rdrr, is there a reason you refuse to indicate some of your examples?